# Data types - Difference between data.array and array

Tags: julia

So i am using Indicators package and the sma function. The sma function is setup like this:

```
function sma(x::Array{Float64}; n::Int64=10)::Array{Float64}
    return runmean(x, n=n, cumulative=false)
end
```

Its input is an Array{Float64}.

So I load my data into a df with types:

```
julia> showcols(df)
6258×7 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Col # │ Name      │ Eltype  │ Missing │
├───────┼───────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1     │ Date      │ Date    │ 0       │
│ 2     │ Open      │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 3     │ High      │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 4     │ Low       │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 5     │ Close     │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 6     │ Adj_Close │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 7     │ Volume    │ Int64   │ 0       │
```

I then try run the sma function directly over a data frame column like below:

```
df[:Close_200sma] = sma(df[:Close],n=200)
```

it reports back:

```
MethodError: no method matching sma(::DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}; n=200
```

I see the type is:

```
6258-element DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}
```

DataArrays is a data structure which allows missing values so I read here:

https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataArrays.jl

I imported the data with:

```
df = readtable("SPY.csv", header=true)
```

So not sure how it converted to data.array structure.

When I pull the data frame column to a vector and use convert() to an Array:

```
    Close = Float64[]
    Close = vec(df[:Close]) # 
6258-element DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}

# I use convert to direct array to drop the dataarray structure:
    Close = convert(Array, Close) # Float64[6258]
```

I can run this just fine through the sma function:

```
sma(Close,n=200)
```

When i check showcols(df)

```
julia> showcols(df)
6258×7 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Col # │ Name      │ Eltype  │ Missing │
├───────┼───────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1     │ Date      │ Date    │ 0       │
│ 2     │ Open      │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 3     │ High      │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 4     │ Low       │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 5     │ Close     │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 6     │ Adj_Close │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 7     │ Volume    │ Int64   │ 0       │
```

eltype is Float64. Because its wrapped into the datarray structure, I am unable to pass it to the SMA function which is setup for Float64 only.

Am I correct in saying its not working because of the datarray structure and its why I am unable to have it work directly into the data frame?

I had this call working fine when I used read.CSV() from package CSV, however it started to throw the null error and was overwriting other files. So i dropped the CSV package for now.

```
dt = CSV.read("SPY.csv", types=[String; fill(Float64, 5); Int])
```

Here I had the capability to specify the types and i was able to run the df column to the sma() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your question, but I believe it boils down to: why can't you call your `sma` function you defined with a `DataArray`?

Well, it is because you demand that your `sma` function only works with `Array{Float64}` and it must only return things that are `Array{Float64}`.  `DataArray{Float64}`, as you've discovered is *not* an `Array{Float64}`.  It's another kind of array (with a lowercase "a" array).  It is, however, an `AbstractArray{Float64}`.  Lots of custom array objects have been implemented that look, act, and behave just like the builtin `Array` but have special properties.  In this case, the special property is specialized handling for missing values.

So you have two options:

- You can either implement your methods to accept and possibly return any `AbstractArray{Float64}`.  This is generally considered good style if you're not relying on any special internal behavior — and just using indexing as the API into the array.
- Or you can explicitly convert your `DataArray` to an `Array` before you call them.  You can do this with `convert(Array{Float64}, A)` — but note that it'll throw an error if any of the elements are missing.